# C# : Serialization of simple class

Tags: c#, serialization

I tried the (modified and simplified) MSDN exemple of basic serialization at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx

```
//the class :
[Serializable]
public class MyObject {
  public byte n1 = 0;
  public byte n2 = 0;
}

//The code
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.n1 = 1;
obj.n2 = 24;
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
stream.Close();
```

So, i expect to find 2 bytes : 0x01 0x18 in MyFile.bin
but it's not like this, i have this result:

[image]

Why is there all this. and how can i do what i would like.

The aim of this test is to serialize more complexe structure in order to save them to a binary file

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` add some metadata about the structure. But even if you neglect it - `int` has 4 bytes each, why do you expect to see 2 bytes having two 4-byted `Int32` structures?

Comment: You should use the `using` statement for the stream, to make sure resources are cleaned up in case of an exception. `Close()` is not safe enough, because it might crash before it gets to that statement.

Comment: Sorry, i fail to correct before posting the two members of class MyObject are bytes  (but i don't know how to edit my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializer also stores the type information about the object that was serialized.
This information is used during deserialization so the instances of appropriate classes are instantiated.

I would like to suggest you take a look at [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for binary serialisation. It's fast and handles changes to classes better than `BinaryFormatter`. It would be probably safer than inventing own serialization mechanism.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the OPs question

Comment: And what about the most unambiguous part `and how can i do what i would like` ?

Comment: About the ambigous part of my question: I mean "How can i have in my result file the only 2 bytes that i have in my class?"

Comment: @user2192443 - You will have to implement custom serlialization. The problem is that `Int32` has *4* bytes and you want to store it in *1* byte - you're going to loose data.

Comment: @ Jakub Konecki. Thanks, i made a mistake when posting.  there are bytes. now i have correct the question

Comment: @user2192443 - My answer stays unchanged: implement custom serialization (google for tutorials), or if you've never implemented it yourself save lots of trouble and use a library that does it properly. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The serialization of a .Net object is complex. It also stores metadata to regenerate the .Net class so don't expect it to be aligned according to class members. It is a proprietary format and only .Net framework can deserialize the class.

If you want to serialize in that way, you should write your custom serialization function which overrides the default and serialize/deserialize the class your own.